# Develop 'Mention' feature to UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

[image: Facebook/KakaoStory Mention feature]

I want to make this feature, i did try many ways, but i couldn't find answer.

1. `UITextView + NSAttritubtedString`

   - I think this is best way, but cannot applied to iOS 5. Only over iOS 6.
2. [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) (`UITextView` + Overlay `UILabel` + CoreText)

   - Work well in English/Korean characters, but problem occured in japanese/chinese.
3. [`JSTokenField`](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField) (or other Token Libraries)

   - We need `UITextView` for supporting multiline, but these are `UITextField`.

I spent more than 4 days for this problem.. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you really have to support iOS versions prior to iOS 6, then maybe you should take a look at the UITextInput protocol (and related stuff): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Using this, I've managed to implement a custom component for bankcard-number input, and I think it's certainly possible what you're trying to achieve (although it would take a few days of experimenting to get a good grasp of this stuff).

Comment: What is `bankcard-number`? I'm having a hard time making UI.

Comment: The numbers on a credit card. I've mentioned it, because it was somewhat similar what you're trying to achieve: text input w/ highly custom rendering.